# Compress production main.js in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, node-modules, angular7

I am trying to compile production build using Angular 7. where I am not sure how can I compress the main.js or split into pieces. Using below snippet for budgeting.

```js
"budgets": [{
                "type": "bundle",
                "name": "vendor",
                "baseline": "750kb",
                "warning": "100kb",
                "error": "200kb"
              }]
```

[image]

Comment: If you split your main code into multiple modules and use lazy loading that will split your main module.  I am not sure if that technique can be used to split the vendor module or not.